# Install wifi driver for Macbook 11.1 under Tails

Tags: debian, wifi, macintosh, broadcom, tails-os

I am having some troubles with the WIFI on my Macbook using Tails (USB). I encountered a problem similar once when setting up an Arch Linux USB system but I as able to find the necessary drivers and install them properly (Arch doc is very well done).

However I have absolutely no idea how to do this in Tails (or Debian in general). I don't have ethernet so I need to download manually the packages and install them manually on the system after.

The device is Broadcom 14e4:43a0.

How should I achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't even think one second that android tethering would work out of the box but it did. I was able to connect to the internet from Tails OS. However installing drivers didn't work because of a kernel update that couln't be install. I think it is not compatible with Tails OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the time to dig into this. We need to install the wl driver for the `14E4:43A0` chip.

Here are the steps :

1. Enable non-free in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file
2. `apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms`
3. `modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac` to remove drivers that may conflict
4. `modprobe wl` to enable the driver

On Tails OS, this won't be saved after reboot.

**IMPORTANT EDIT :**

[You should not do this](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/10658/is-loading-wl-driver-for-macbook-wifi-at-start-up-safe-on-tails-os).

Comment: I don't have a Mac, but I have an usupported USB-Wifi adapter also. So I could either use Ethernet cable, or use USB tethering from my Android phone. Works nicely most of the time. Occasionally it needs a tethering off/on cycle.